# How to sort a list by the number of / in an element?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to sort a list that contains folder paths as each element. The elements should be sorted in ascending order by the number of sub-folders. Each `/` represents a sub folder. Stand alone folder should be at the top of the list.  A sample list would look like:

`sports = ['Sports/Soccer/Spain/First Division', 'Sports/Soccer/Spain', 'Sports/Soccer', Sports/Soccer/England', 'Sports']`

expected end result is:
`['Sports', 'Sports/Soccer', Sports/Soccer/England','Sports/Soccer/Spain', 'Sports/Soccer/Spain/La Liga']`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to sort it in place:

```
sports.sort(key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
```

For a new sorted list:

```
result = sorted(sports, key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
```